# How to get WebView to wrap an image exactly

Tags: android

I am using a WebView to display some maps in my app using the Google Static Maps API. However, when I load a map into my WebView, it's always either zoomed out too far (showing a massive amount of white space around the map) or too close (showing only part of the map). Given that I'm requesting a map of the same size as the size of my WebView, I should be able to "tightly" wrap with no issues, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I've tried just running at the default settings, and that results in the map being zoomed in too far (and scrollbars being displayed). I've also tried this:

```
mapView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mapView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

which just results in the page being fully zoomed out. Are there other alternatives I'm missing other than futzing around with the scale?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with the whitespace. What I did was to go into the CSS file for the WebView and edited the margin/padding on the image I was displaying to be negative (I just edited until I was happy) so it would display completely in the upper left corner.

Then I set the height and width of the webView in my Android XML file until I was happy with the result. However I was having a bit of a problem with the width showing some white space on some devices but the height was good once I had found the right value.

My solution to this was to try to set the width as the same as the height in the java.class file for the activity but I was not successful, maybe you will have more luck.

In the end I abandoned the webView for my project so I can't really give you any working code.